# Flutter app can't be run in emulator on Linux mint

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, emulation

i'm working on my first project on android studio using flutter
I created the default project by `flutter create project_name`,but when i run it with `flutter run` ,i wait a lot of time but no result ...

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get
graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

And it still like that :/
i was working on windows and it was perfectly working but after fixing all problems that faces me to run it on linux mint tina ,i finish by getting no result 
**But after a mount of time i got these errors**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /home/simo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.6.2-all/9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       120.3s (!)
[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /home/simo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.6.2-all/9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                  
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       120.2s (!)
[!] Gradle threw an error while trying to update itself. Retrying the update...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What can i do to fix that ? Thank you in advance !
***And when i run that :*** `flutter run -v --enable-software-rendering`

```
[  +15 ms] executing: [/home/simo/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log
-n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +25 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [/home/simo/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.*
--first-parent --long --tags
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long
--tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +7 ms] executing: [/home/simo/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
--symbolic @{u}
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/simo/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +42 ms] executing: [/home/simo/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +83 ms] executing: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
-l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86
           model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
[  +16 ms] /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell
getprop
[  +33 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[ +124 ms] Generating
/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plug
ins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +23 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +31 ms] Using software rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. You
may get
           better performance with hardware mode by configuring hardware
rendering for your
           device.
[  +16 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[  +10 ms] executing: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554
shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +25 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of system
           02-19 13:26:36.363 W/AppOps  ( 2133): Noting op not finished: uid
           10102 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1582115190374
           duration=0
[   +7 ms] executing: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[        ] executing: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554
logcat -v time -T 02-19 13:26:36.363
[  +26 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.5-5949299
           Installed as /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/simo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +11 ms] Building APK
[  +18 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +2 ms] Using gradle from
/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/gradlew.
[   +8 ms] executing: /home/simo/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/simo/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_202-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
           1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b49-5587405, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/]
/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/lib/main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root
-Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[ +145 ms] Downloading
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

Comment: 'Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get
graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"**--enable-software-rendering**".'

Comment: Yeah i did but the same problem , my garphical card nvidia GFORCE 130M and i7 processor ,i don't think that make a problem

Comment: i had a blank screen on my linux mint too, using `--enable-software-rendering` did a trick, what do you see if you run `flutter run -v --enable-software-rendering` from the terminal?

Comment: the poste has been updated .you can see its output

Comment: so it worked or not?

Comment: no,am i downloading a zip file ? 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
'

Comment: good, wait till it finishes

Comment: blocked here :/

Comment: [        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_202-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
           1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b49-5587405, mixed mode)
[  +18 ms] executing: [/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/]
/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=/home/simo/Documents/first_app_flutter/lib/main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root
-Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
`

Comment: so did `flutter run ...` show your app?

Comment: unfortunately ,no

Comment: what is error message then?

Comment: the same **problem** , i should wait and i get  the same output ...and when i re-run the command that provided earlier it shows :[+3539 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use
--status for details

Comment: did you install flutter that way: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux ?

Comment: yeah exactly the same way

Comment: `flutter doctor` shows `Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!`

Comment: tried some physical device?

Comment: humm.. Okay i will try that

Comment: That's work perfectly ,thank you so much for the time you give for supporting ... i just rerun that command `flutter run -v --enable-software-rendering` and i restarted the computer and it works

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is 1 year old, I will share my experience for those who will face the issue.

I also faced this issue and I tried the below steps and it worked for me.

1. open the terminal inside your project.
2. execute the command  `flutter clean`
3. execute the command  `flutter run`